# How to serve gRPC and REST with TLS enable on the same port

Tags: rest, go, grpc

I'm trying to create a gRPC/REST PoC written in Go.

I would like to serve the gRPC and REST on the same port, in a TLS connection. I'm also using serving metrics.

1. When accessing my service through HTTP/1, all is working as expected
2. When accessing the /metrics url, all is working as expected
3. When accessing the gRPC service directly, using a client I received a connection close response

I do not know how to debug this kind of error.

I have created a repo on https://github.com/lrobinot/grpc-poc to reproduce the issue.

Can someone give me pointers to some resources or show me my enormous error :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need the same port? There's 65536 to choose from!

Comment: This is an idea! But when exposing your service, one port for one service is juste enough :)